# kubernetes Service select multi labels

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have two StatefulSets named `my-sts` and `my-sts-a`, want to create **a single service**, that addresses **same-indexed pods**, **from two different StatefulSets**, like: `my-sts-0`  and `my-sts-a-0`.  But found [k8s doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#service-and-replicationcontroller) says:

> Labels selectors for both objects are defined in json or yaml files using maps, and only equality-based requirement selectors are supported

My idea is to create a label for the two sts pods like:

```
my-sts-0 has label abc:sts-0
my-sts-a-0 has label abc:sts-0

my-sts-1 has label abc:sts-1
my-sts-a-1 has label abc:sts-1
```

How to get the index of those pods so that I can create a label named `abc=sts-<index>` to approach it?

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes [already gives you a DNS name to select individual StatefulSet pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id).  Say you have a Service `my-sts` that matches every pod in the StatefulSet, and the StatefulSet is set up with `serviceName: my-sts`; then you can access host names `my-sts-0.my-sts.namespace.svc.cluster.local` and so on.

If you specifically want a service to target a specific pod, there is also a [`statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name` label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#pod-name-label) that gets added automatically, so you can attach to that

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-sts-master
spec:
  selector:
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: my-sts-0
  ports: [...]
```

Comment: But this service cannot select another sts pod `my-sts-a-0`, do you mean that create two service select two sts and then create the third service to select the two service?

Comment: ...you want a single service, that addresses same-indexed pods, from two different StatefulSets?  I'm not sure there's enough metadata you can match on; ExternalName services might help, but a service can only reference one name.  Hmm.

Comment: Yes. And I tried to create an ExternalName service to address two pods but failed.